# Mocking resultset getTimeStamp doesn't work for more thans 1 row

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I am trying to mock a java.sql.resultset in my unit test case. I am using mocikto and junit for assertions. All the call to next and getString being mocked work properly, but when i try to mock getTimestamp it works only for first row i.e first resultset.

```
when(statement.getResultSet()).thenReturn(resultSet);
    when(resultSet.next()).thenReturn(true).thenReturn(true).thenReturn(true).thenReturn(true).thenReturn(true).thenReturn(false);
    when(resultSet.getString("HIST_ID"))
   .thenReturn("").thenReturn("").thenReturn("").thenReturn("").thenReturn("");
when(resultSet.getTimestamp("CREATED_ON")).thenReturn(Timestamp.valueOf("2017-02-06 14:16:39.78"))
.thenReturn(Timestamp.valueOf("2017-02-08 11:29:31.3"))
.thenReturn(Timestamp.valueOf("2017-02-08 11:29:57.49"))
.thenReturn(Timestamp.valueOf("2017-02-08 11:30:13.47"))
.thenReturn(Timestamp.valueOf("2017-02-08 11:30:33.91"));
```

I tried to debug it and found that the call .thenReturn(Timestamp.valueOf("2017-02-08 11:29:31.3")) gives this exception:-

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.WrongTypeOfReturnValue: 
Timestamp cannot be returned by toString()
```

This code works for one row but the next row it starts giving the above exception.

The calling function has this code-

```
while (rs != null && rs.next()) {
        resp = new ClassA();
        resp.setCreatedDt(rs.getTimestamp("CREATED_ON"));
}
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks
Tausif

Comment: I tried instead of chaining the thenReturn call for the Timestamp i converted it to thenReturn(Timestamp.valueOf("2017-02-06 14:16:39.78"),Timestamp.valueOf("2017-02-08 11:29:31.3"), )

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Could you show the the part of code where `resultSet.getTimestamp("CREATED_ON")` is called?

Comment: Updated as per your request @SergheyBishyr. Also i was able to solve this issue using thenReturn(Timestamp.valueOf("2017-02-06 14:16:39.78"),Timestamp.valueOf("2017-02-08 11:29:31.3")) instead of chaining methods. Thanks for replying.

Comment: I'm still unable to reproduce this issue. Which `Mockito` version are you using?

Comment: I am using mockito-all-1.9.5.jar and junit-4.11.jar

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve this issue by replacing the above code with this

```
thenReturn(Timestamp.valueOf("2017-02-06 14:16:39.78"),Timestamp.valueOf("2017-02-08 11:29:31.3"))
```

instead of chaining methods. 
Complete code:-

```
when(statement.getResultSet()).thenReturn(resultSet);
when(resultSet.next()).thenReturn(true).thenReturn(true).thenReturn(true).thenReturn(true).thenReturn(true).thenReturn(false);
when(resultSet.getString("HIST_ID")).thenReturn("").thenReturn("").thenReturn("").thenReturn("").thenReturn("");
when(resultSet.getTimestamp("CREATED_ON")).thenReturn(Timestamp.valueOf("2017-02-06 14:16:39.78"),Timestamp.valueOf("2017-02-08 11:29:31.3"), Timestamp.valueOf("2017-02-08 11:29:57.49"), Timestamp.valueOf("2017-02-08 11:30:13.47"), Timestamp.valueOf("2017-02-08 11:30:33.91"));
```

Though this solved my issue i am still not sure how this got solved by doing this.